# how to compile scala and java files to together in netbeans IDE?

Tags: java, scala, netbeans

I have checked all the related questions about this issue. The issue i have is, i have scala code and java code in same netbeans project.  The home env for scala is set. I use windows system for the development. I know that the build.xml of the netbeans project needs to be changed, to compile scala code first and then compile the java code. But i couldnt find much of example to do this on netbeans IDE.

Comment: http://jglobal.com/scala-and-java-together/

Answer (score 0):

I use the netbeans sbt plugin (nbsbt).  It takes care of this transparently.

Comment: I installed all the plugins of scala in the netbeans ide. Still i get the class not found error and when i checked class files,the scala class files where not generated.

Comment: What happens if you compile using sbt only?  IE from the command prompt?  If that doesn't work then nbsbt won't either.

Comment: i could compile my scala code using scalac from command promt. i tried that before,it works.

Comment: I suggest you install sbt and get your project compiling with that before you try to use Netbeans / nbsbt.

Answer (score 0):

Only tangentially related, but Intellij Idea using pom (maven) projects handles this with no issues whatsoever.  You just create a src/main/scala dir alongside your srce/main/java and use the Scala complier plug-in:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.scala-tools</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-scala-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>test-compile</id>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

I offer this only for those who may be pondering NetBeans vs. Idea for Scala development.